# Doing a while in bash script conditioned on the contents of a file?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file, call it `out`, which has a single line. The contents of that line are either a real number, or the string `"Continue"`.

I have a bash script, where I execute some commands, which result in the file `out` being modified. I need to keep executing the commands while the single line of `out` equals `"Continue"`.

How do I do this using a bash script?

In other words, I need to do a `while`, on the condition that the contents of the file `out` equal `"Continue"`. How?

Comment: Some more details would be useful. What is it that is modifying the file? It sounds like you don't need to write to the file at all until the end of the loop.

Comment: @TomFenech Inside the loop, I run an executable, which writes to the file. I thought that wasn't relevant so I didn't add it to the question. If you think so, I can edit.

Comment: @becko Something like `while [[ $(<file) =~ 'Continue' ]]; do ... ; done` ?

Comment: @BroSlow I suppose. What is `file`? Is it a string path to the file? And what is `=~`?

Comment: @becko Yes, that's what it is.

Comment: @BroSlow So `$(<file)` is a variable containing the contents of `file`?

Comment: Yes, it's equivalent to `$(cat file)`, except faster. Objectively better to read files line by line when the files are big, but obviously doesn't matter here

Comment: @becko Have to go, so went ahead and posted it as answer after checking that it worked. `== Continue` is equivalent to `=~ ^Continue$`, which I think is what's wanted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest syntax would be to do something like.

```
while [[ $(<file) == Continue ]]; do ... ; done
```

Where `$(<file)` is equivilent to `$(cat file)` but faster.

Comment: Why would you want to add a 1 second delay? The `while` condition will only be evaluated once every time the inner body of the loop has completed.

Comment: @TomFenech Yeah. Doing anything in the body would delay it on its own and doesn't seem to be that intensive on my system, so removed that part.

Comment: @TomFenech I'm confused, where is this 1 sec delay supposedly hiding?